# isset($_POST['tag-name']) is set but $_POST['tag-name'] return empty when selecting dynamic list

Tags: php

I has created dynamic list in php.

```
<select name="student" >
    <option selected disable class="hideoption">Student Name</option>
   <?php
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        echo<option value='".$row['path']."'>'".$row['studentName']."'</option>";
     }
  ?>   
</select>
```

When I'm selected the list it give empty string. But when I'm not selected anything it return the first value which is `Student Name`. I tried to get the value from this line.

```
if(isset($_POST['student'])){ 
   $selectedName = $_POST['student'];
}
```

I also try to checked whether the `isset` is set or empty. The `isset` is set but its empty.
This is the only solution `Google` provided.Ideas?

**Edit**

I have **solved** the problem. The explanation on the answer below.

Comment: Not sure, but you should have a space here: 'echo<optionvalue', so try to separate option tag and attribute...

Comment: That was error while copy in this forum. Edited.

Comment: This code generates an error and would never show your list. You need to post the real code you are using.

Comment: It shows my list sir. The problem is I tried to get the selected value. While I'm trying to use everyone solution, I get a down vote. What a shame for me as a absolute newbie. I spent more than 10 hour before decided to post in here. What a joke.

Comment: You get a downvote because you are not posting the code you are using so nobody can tell what the exact problem is apart from the syntax error that you obviously don't have yourself. This is what your php does when you copy and paste it: https://eval.in/677799

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought `$_POST['student']` returning the text inside the `<option>` tag and I was wrong. I learnt that it return the value which is should be set in `<option>` attribute, So I just set the value to `$row['studentName']`, because `$row['path']` returned empty string. Correct me if what I said is wrong. So basically, the code looks like below.

```
<select name="student" >
  <option selected disable class="hideoption">Student Name</option>
  <?php
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        echo<option value='".$row['studentName']."'>'".$row['studentName']."'</option>";
     }
 ?>   
</select>
```

Thanks for all your responses. Your responses made me think what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<select name="student" id="student" >
    <option selected disable class="hideoption">Student Name</option>
   <?php
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        echo "<option name='".$row['studentName']."' value='".$row['path']."'>'".$row['studentName']."'</option>";
   }?>   
</select>
```

Comment: also your echo statement not proper. Please change it like i have done.

Comment: Add `name='".$row['studentName']."'` attribute in option tag. @dongcheng

Answer (score 0):

You should be use this line `isset($_POST['studentName']) && $selected  = $_POST['studentName'] == $row['studentName'] ? 'selected = "selected"' :  null;` for selected `option`

```
<select name="student" >
   <option selected disable class="hideoption">Student Name</option>
   <?php
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $selected = isset($_POST['studentName']) && $_POST['studentName'] == $row['studentName'] ? 'selected = "selected"' :  null;
        echo "<option ".$selected." value='".$row['path']."'>".$row['studentName']."</option>";
   }
   ?>   
</select>
```

Comment: if you not clarify your problem, you can not solve this. please clarify your actual prblme

Answer (score 0):

@dongcheng This is the same code but with better alignments. So you can see your code clearly.

```
<select name="student">
    <option selected disable class="hideoption">Student Name</option>
   <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['path'] . '">' . $row['studentName'] . '</option>';
     }
   ?>   
</select>
```

use

```
$selectedStudent = !empty($_POST['student']) ? $_POST['student'] : '';
if ($selectedStudent) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. But the selectedStudent is already returning an empty.

Comment: Thing you need to check

Comment: Things you need to check
=====================

* action & method attributes of the form
* check the values when submit the form via the developer tools in browser (network tab in firefox devtools) 

if it's ok add the page source(html) of the form file. use https://pastebin.mozilla.org/

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/iXMKE using this you can verify that you actually send the relevant data